# How to determine whether a memory address is free in OS?

Tags: linker, operating-system, kernel

Suppose i create a function pointer in kernel(similar to interrupt service routine and maintaining the address of the function in the interrupt vector table) and start compiling and linking,then linker would probably assign the address of the function statically from where it should be executed.

The kernel developer might not  know the address of the function from where it might be executed.

But when a new kernel process is created, it should allocate memory dynamically for the process.
So,how to determine if there is free memory in RAM and allocate the memory to the process?
Also how to find the memory addresses allocated by linker?

I would like to know how malloc or kmalloc allocates free memory to process.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you haven't specified your OS. You're asking how the OS specific kernel memory manager work. That's not something that's exposed in closed OS such as windows. In open source OS you can just browse the code of kmalloc or similar function. But you really shouldn't mess with it unless you know very well what you're doing.

Linker doesn't decide where to load the code, it just resolves the locations of various items in the code and makes proper links between them (that's why it's called linker...)

Answer (score 0):

> So,how to determine if there is free memory in RAM and allocate the
>   memory to the process? Also how to find the memory addresses allocated
>   by linker?

I think you are confused here. These are *virtual* addresses and that is what libraries like `malloc` is about. The mapping to the actual memory addresses and whether there is free memory in the system to run the process is handled transparently by the OS